# alter several alternative substrings to another substring in single mysql query

Tags: mysql

Is there an opportunity to use such a query in mysql for substring replacement as below but for several words instead of single "a"?

```
UPDATE table1 SET field = REPLACE ("a bb ccc dddddd eeeeeee", 'a', 'z')
```

I mean to look for "a" OR "bb" OR "ccc" and replece all of them to "z" instead of making several queries changing "a" to "bb" and "ccc"?
Thank you

Comment: So you want that all the pattern like `a` or `aa` or `aaaaaaa` should be replaced by single `b`? You can edit your question and add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html then clarify your question

Comment: I edited the question. I need to look for several substrings ("a", "bb", "ccc") in a string "a bb ccc dddddd eeeeeee" and alter them to substring "bb". I need this will be the single query, not several ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chain of REPLACE function like this:

```
replace(replace('"a bb ccc dddddd eeeeeee','a','z'),'b','z')
```

You cannot change it in a single Replace function.

Comment: if I need also look for "c" than it will be: replace(replace(replace('"a bb ccc dddddd eeeeeee','a','z'),'b','z')'c','z') ?